# SFML Window Not Rendering Shape

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is directly from the tutorial's page, and I've checked and rechecked, so I know this is not a syntax or linker error.

When I run this program, I get a window whose contents are the same as whatever the place it is located in. Yet, if I remove the `window.draw(shape)` command, I see a black window, like I should.

I'm compiling on Windows 7 (32 bit) using mingw32-g++.exe (4.7.1). Oh, and it's the same if I compile debug or release and static or dynamic, so that's not the problem either.

Comment: You followed everything and read the warnings?: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php

Comment: Yes, I get no linker or compiler errors and the window appears. It's what is inside the window that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but to me it looks like you need to set the position of your circle. I maybe wrong here but the position could be any value and that is why it isn't displaying.

Could you try updating your code to this please.

```
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
shape.setPosition(50f, 50f);
shape.setScale(2,2); // You can remove this line if you want to, I just put it there for debugging

while (window.isOpen())
{
    ...
```

Here is the SFML documentation for setPosition (http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a4dbfb1a7c80688b0b4c477d706550208)

Here is the SFML documentation for setScale (http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#aaec50b46b3f41b054763304d1e727471)

Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I believe the default position for sfml transformable is 0,0. It should be in the top left corner.